# Passing variable argument list

Tags: php

Given the redundancy, is there a better way to do this? If so, what would it look like?

Note the first `$method` argument, which is passed as a function name within the `$api` class, and must not be passed as an argument to the API function. Every argument thereafter might not exist.

```
function jsonRequest( $method )
{
    $api = new JsonRpcClient( 'https://api.example.com' );
    switch ( func_num_args() ) {
        case 2:
            $result = $api->$method( 'AccountRef', 'APIKey', func_get_arg( 1 ) );
        break; case 3:
            $result = $api->$method( 'AccountRef', 'APIKey', func_get_arg( 1 ), func_get_arg( 2 ) );
        break; case 4:
            $result = $api->$method( 'AccountRef', 'APIKey', func_get_arg( 1 ), func_get_arg( 2 ), func_get_arg( 3 ) );
        break; case 5:
            $result = $api->$method( 'AccountRef', 'APIKey', func_get_arg( 1 ), func_get_arg( 2 ), func_get_arg( 3 ), func_get_arg( 4 ) );
        break;
    }
    return json_decode( $result );
}
```

Comment: What would that look like? I considered it but couldn't get my head around the syntax required for throwing that into a function call.

Comment: Can you pass `func_get_arg( 2 )` or `NULL` for the extended args?

Comment: here function takes one argument only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `call_user_func_array`:

```
$data = array_merge(array('AccountRef', 'APIKey'), func_get_args());

call_user_func_array(array($api, $method), $data);
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

Comment: Awesome, I completely overlooked that function thinking it was irrelevant. D'oh! Just need to remove $method from that array now.

Comment: @AndrewBestic - Don't forget to mark it as the answer if it works. You do this by clicking the outlined checkmark to the right of the question (note, only one answer can be "accepted" per question).

Comment: Was able to remove initial argument with: `$args = func_get_args(); unset( $args[0] );`

Comment: Instead of defining $method as your first argument, just use `func_get_args()` to fetch all the arguments into an array. Then you can use `$method = array_shift($args)` to populate the method variable and clean your `$args` array at the same time.